# How to execute middleware before accessing any route list in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm trying to create a simple module based saas application in laravel. For creating modules, I've used https://github.com/nWidart/laravel-modules. All modules: user and site modules; with respective file structure resides under Modules. Both of above mentioned modules have their respective routes. I was trying to create a middleware in site module and use it in app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider so that no routes in any module passthru without checking in middleware. For this I tried to create a Route group for domain in the very beginning of routes/web.php

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{domain}', 'middleware' => ['site']], function() {

});
```

but it isn't calling site middleware for any check. I really appreciate any help on this.

Code: https://github.com/itsursujit/boot-vue/tree/module_manager

Comment: You are getting any error?

Comment: No any error while checking above

Comment: Your middle-ware is registered ?

Comment: Yes I registered that as middleware, routeMiddleware in Kernel.php but no luck

Comment: Where is your middleware class

Comment: @GeomiGeorge `Modules\Site\Http\Middleware\SiteMiddleware`

Comment: Is this your whole route group function? How did you specify any routes in it? Also, which version of Laravel do you use?

Comment: routes are handled in each modules defined. Each routes have its own prefix based on modules. For e.g. `/blog/index`, `/address/index`. So what I wanted to achieve here is none of the routes in module be accessible unless validated by application or middleware